# I need to add a sidebar to the right of my content

Tags: html, css, styling

I got an assignment to make a website for the "Olympic boxing tournament", which needs to include a right sidebar. I tried for almost a day now but i can't seem to find a way to let it appear next to the main content section.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="content-main content-style">
 <h1>Hier komt de content van de main sectie.</h1>
 <p>Mooie content </p>
</div>

<div class="content-right content-style">
 <h1>Hier komt de content van de right-sidebar</h1>
 <p>mooie content he?</p>
</div>
```

And here the CSS :

```
.content-style {
    background-color:rgba(120, 135, 171,0.5);
    text-align:center;
}
 .content-main {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 450px;
}

.content-right{
   width: 15%;
   float:right;
   position: relative;
}
```

I think it should be a very easy thing; I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your

```
.content-main {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 450px;
}
```

To

```
.content-main {
    width: 50%;
    position:absolute;
    left: 450px;
}
```

This will not only place the sidebar where you want it to be, but also position the element, instead of pushing it sideways, leaving you with more room on the lefthand side of the `.content-main`

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t8gLeov8/1/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: There seem to be somthing wrong in your solution the two divs overlaping each other.

Comment: This has to do with the size of the window you're viewing it from @MartinGodzina simply make the screen larger and it'll be fine

Comment: With the right CSS settings it would never happen that the divs overlap. Check Anton´s answer pls =)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vuev1671/).

Please notice that the floating element should come first. That is the main point.

```
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="content-right content-style">
 <h1>Hier komt de content van de right-sidebar</h1>
 <p>mooie content he?</p>
</div>

<div class="content-main content-style">
 <h1>Hier komt de content van de main sectie.</h1>
 <p>Mooie content </p>
</div>

</div>

.content-style {
    background-color:rgba(120, 135, 171,0.5);
    text-align:center;
}
 .content-main {
    width: 80%;
}

.content-right{
   width: 15%;
   float:right;
   position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without changing your markup, this is the CSS you need. The CSS on the wrapper is to ensure that it properly surrounds the floated elements. This is usually applied as a class called `clearfix`, as you'll use it often.

```css
.wrapper:before,
.wrapper:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.wrapper:after {
  clear: both;
}

.content-style {
  background-color: rgba(120, 135, 171, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
}

.content-main {
  float: left;
  width: 84%;
}

.content-right {
  width: 15%;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}
```